# Assigning an object from Parse.Query to a global variable

Tags: java, android, variables, object, parse-platform

I'm trying to access a variable inside a query from parse but it gets destroyed when the query finishes.
As you can see in the code below, I output it into the console and it does work, but if I try to assign it to a variable and then use it it returns null. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Hospitales");
            query.whereEqualTo("Codigo", id);
            query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (object == null) {
                        Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("id", "Retrieved the object.");
                        String status = object.getString("Hospital");
                        m2Status = object.getString("Hospital");
                        System.out.println("Hospital: " + status);
                        System.out.println(status + m2Status);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I see how you're assigning "Hospital" to a variable, but what is `m2Status`, where is it declared, and how are you trying to access it in another context?

Comment: I assigned it in the top of the class (but in the class) as: Protected String m2Status. I'm trying to access it outside the Query to add it to a new user with user.put("Hospital", m2Status);
When I run it it gives a null value when I use m2Status outside the Query, but when I use inside it does indeed give the value I need.

Comment: And are you sure you're only trying to access the value after it's been populated by the query? I assume you're aware that the query runs asynchronously, right?

Comment: How could I make it work ? By giving it a little bit of time between the query and when I want to use the variable ?

Comment: You absolutely **HAVE** to wait until the query runs successfully. If not, how can you have the data/object stored into any variable? Generally, I would suggest to call the method that needs to access the returned variable **AFTER** the query returns you the variable, but **HOW** you set that up is specific to the problem.

Comment: How can I run a function after the Query returned me a value ? Sorry for the newbie skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically, your problem seems to be that you're running an asynchronous query and trying to access the variable before that query has returned.

Here's how you could set up your code to defer using the variable until you can be reasonably sure you have a value to actually use:

```
private void runQuery() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Hospitales");
    query.whereEqualTo("Codigo", id);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object == null) {
                Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
                // You don't have a good value to use, so figure
                // out a way to handle that scenario
            } else {
                Log.d("id", "Retrieved the object.");
                String status = object.getString("Hospital");
                m2Status = object.getString("Hospital");
                System.out.println("Hospital: " + status);
                System.out.println(status + m2Status);
                // You have a good value to use, so
                // now you can actually use it
                afterQueryProcessing();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void afterQueryProcessing() {
    // You can access m2Status here reliably,
    // assuming you only call this method
    // as shown above, but you should still
    // use defensive programming
    if (m2Status != null) {
        // Now you know you have a value to use...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a ton for all the help! You were really descriptive and I got what I needed working :D!

Comment: @MauricioSilva Awesome! Happy to help! Keep striving to learn as much as you can!